# PHP - in_array function working correctly when detecting URL's

Tags: php, xml, arrays

The code below is being used to retrieve the value of the "store" element from the XML file below and insert the values into an array (the storeArray). I do NOT want duplicate values put into the array (IE I don't want Best Buy inserted twice), so I am using the in_array method to prevent duplication.

This code works fine:

$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
$storeArray = array();

```
foreach($xmlDoc->product as $Product) {
echo "Name: " . $Product->name . ", ";
echo "Price: " . $Product->price . ", ";

if( !in_array( (string)$Product->store, $storeArray )) {
    $storeArray[] = (string)$Product->store;
}}

foreach ($storeArray as $store) {
echo $store . "<br>"; 
}
```

But when I try to put those array values (from the XML store element) into a link (like below), the values are duplicated (IE Best Buy is displayed twice. Any advice?

```
if( !in_array( (string)$Product->store, $storeArray )) {
$storeArray[] = "<a href='myLink.htm'>" . (string)$Product->store . "</a>";

foreach ($storeArray as $store) {
echo $store . "<br>";
}
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<product type="Electronics">
<name> Desktop</name>
<price>499.99</price>
<store>Best Buy</store>
</product>

<product type="Electronics">
<name>Lap top</name>
<price>599.99</price>
<store>Best Buy</store>
</product>

<product type="Hardware">
<name>Hand Saw</name>
<price>99.99</price>
<store>Lowes</store>
</product>

</products>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with your `in_array` check. You are checking if the store is in the array, but actually add the link to the array, therefore `in_array` will always be false.

Bad check:

```
// you are checking the existance of $Product->store
if (!in_array((string)$Product->store, $storeArray)) {
    // but add something else
    $storeArray[] = "<a href='myLink.htm'>" . (string)$Product->store . "</a>";
}
```

Instead try using the store as an array key:

```
$store = (string)$Product->store;

if (!array_key_exists($store, $storeArray)) {
    $storeArray[$store] = "<a href='myLink.htm'>" . $store . "</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Should've realized that in_array will always be false with the link!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine. It won't add the value to $storeArray twice.
I think you have a bug with closing brackets in the second code block you shown.
See this phpfiddle - it works:

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1ph-6rs

**You can also use array_unique() function to print unique values.**